# No Repair option in Programs and Features

Tags: wix, bootstrapper

I have a Wix installer with a mangaged bootstrapper. Everything works as expected.

However, when I right-click on my installed program in the Windows "Programs and Features" window, I only get the options "Deinstall" and "Change".

Is it possible to enable the "Repair" option for this menu?

When calling "Change" I get the window that allows "Deinstall" and "Repair". And repairing works since ARPNOREPAIR is not set but I would like to offer the "Repair" option additionally in the Programs and Features menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a limitation in the bootstrapper:
https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/2719.
It would be nice to have a *Repair* option in ARP.